# SQLAlchemy query result doesn't have attribute `_asdict()`

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this models.

```py
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class PortfolioPerformanceTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = tn.portfolio_performance

    clientuid: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(f"{tn.clients}.clientno"))
    clientno: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(f"{tn.client_strategies}.clientno"))
    clientid: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(f"{tn.custodian_banks}.id"), primary_key=True)

class ConsolidatedHoldingsTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = tn.consolidated_holdings

    clientuid: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(f"{tn.clients}.clientno"))
    clientno: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(f"{tn.client_strategies}.clientno"))
    clientid: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(f"{tn.custodian_banks}.id"), primary_key=True)
    hldsdt: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(DateTime, primary_key=True)  # holdings date
    isin: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(12), primary_key=True)
    bbticker: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100))
    bbmktsectordes: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100))
```

And I use this two query

```py
def get_performances(date: str, clientids: list[str], db: Session):
    query = (
        db.query(PortfolioPerformanceTable.perfdt, PortfolioPerformanceTable.dailyrt)
        .where(PortfolioPerformanceTable.perfdt <= date)
        .where(PortfolioPerformanceTable.clientid.in_(clientids))
        .order_by(PortfolioPerformanceTable.perfdt.desc())
    )

    performances = [row._asdict() for row in query.all()]

    return performances


def get_holdings(clientids: list[str], db: Session):
    query = (
        db.query(ConsolidatedHoldingsTable)
        .filter(
            ConsolidatedHoldingsTable.hldsdt == select(func.max(ConsolidatedHoldingsTable.hldsdt))
        )
        .filter(ConsolidatedHoldingsTable.clientid.in_(clientids))
        .order_by(ConsolidatedHoldingsTable.isin.desc())
    )

    holdings = [row._asdict() for row in query.all()]

    return holdings
```

It's same query. I use the model to query. But strage thing is there are no method `_asdict` on `get_holdings` function. It errored out :

```bash
formance_report
    holdings = get_holdings(custodian_banks, db)
  File "/Users/mandaputra/clients_dashboard/service.py", line 39, in get_holdings
    holdings = [row._asdict() for row in query.all()]  # type: ignore
  File "/Users/mandaputra/clients_dashboard/service.py", line 39, in <listcomp>
    holdings = [row._asdict() for row in query.all()]  # type: ignore
AttributeError: 'ConsolidatedHoldingsTable' object has no attribute '_asdict'
```

I tried to check the type of `row` but, strange thing is the row type form `get_holdings` is `ConsolidatedHoldingsTable` and the row type for `get_performances` is `Row[Tuple[str, float]]`.

How could this happen? And why? Is there any difference when selecting partial column on the model vs all of them

```
db.query(ConsolidatedHoldingsTable)
db.query(ConsolidatedHoldingsTable.nav, ConsolidatedHoldingsTable.isin)
```

How to solve this problem? I want consistent way to convert SQLAlchemy query result to list of dictionaries.